# fetchone() returns none despite the query retrieving data

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm writing a unit test for a method that checks for a value in my db. I've written the following:

```
# Runs SQL query to check if price exists for base date
# If it exists, set the base price to that value
# If it doesn't, set it to 100
def get_base_price(self, month):
    sql = '''SELECT COALESCE(TimeSeriesValue, 100) as TimeSeriesValue
        FROM [RAP].[dbo].[TimeSeriesPosition]
        WHERE TimeSeriesTypeID = 12 AND
              SecurityMasterID = 45889 AND
              FundID = 7 AND
              EffectiveDate = %s''' % month
    with self.job.rap.connect() as conn:
        data = conn.execute(sql).fetchone()
        print(sql)
    return data  # Returns base price value
```

This is the test:

```
# test to grab a base price
def test_retrieving_base_price_if_month_exists(self):
    base_price = self.parser.get_base_price('1990-12-31')
    self.assertEqual(base_price, 108.692339086277)
```

NOTE: `self.parser` is the imported class that contains the methods.

I printed the SQL query in the method and it's executing correctly. I'm guessing the issue is with the way i'm executing the query. I can't seem to figure why it's returning None. It should be returning a row that I can later grab its value with `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query was running the date without quotes:

`1990-12-31`

I had to add triple quotes and wrap the string variable in single quotes. That worked.

Comment: You should use a cursor and a prepared statement instead of string substitution.